# docker-compose stopped working when calling from bash script

Tags: docker-compose

new fresh and clean debian 11
clean docker, docker compose and also docker-compose standalone installation

```
root@a8804:~# docker -v
Docker version 23.0.3, build 3e7cbfd

root@a8804:~# docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.17.2

root@a8804:~# docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
```

```
#!/bin/bash
#start development

export DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-docker-compose-test.yml}
docker-compose -f "$DOCKER_CONFIG" build
#./bin/db_init.sh

docker-compose -f "$DOCKER_CONFIG" up
```

and now it stopped working, no idea why?

this is what I get in the terminal:

```
WARNING: Error loading config file: docker-compose-test.yml/config.json: open docker-compose-test.yml/config.json: not a directory
[+] Running 1/1
 ! graphql Warning                                                                                                                                                                                            1.5s 
mkdir docker-compose-test.yml: not a directory
```

Comment: There's only one thing it could be, right? I've never heard of `DOCKER_CONFIG`, but looking it up [the docs say](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#change-the-docker-directory): "***Change the .docker directory**
To specify a different directory, use the DOCKER_CONFIG environment variable*". Which explains the strange error which suggests Docker is looking for files inside your YML file.  You've specified that a YML file is a directory that Docker should look for various config files in.  So, why are you doing that, or what are you really trying to do?

Comment: as I understand this is not config itself, but a variable for a bash script? So that I don't require to change 'docker-compose-test.yml' text iin multiple lines, just in that one. 


As I find out it is not, so I managed to fixed it by changing this:
```export DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-docker-compose-test.yml}```
to simple this:
```DOCKER_FILE=docker-compose-test.yml```